# Python - iterate two lists and with increment variable

Tags: python

I wanted to iterate through two lists at the same time while also being able to increment a variable:  I am able to achieve this but incrementing row manually.

```
for name, time in zip(Linklist, Timelist):

    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, time)
    row=row+1
```

Trying to see if something like this can be done:

```
for row, name, time in zip(Linklist, Timelist):

    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) and nested unpacking:

```
for row, (name, time) in enumerate(zip(Linklist, Timelist)):
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
for row, name, time in zip(itertools.count(), Linklist, Timelist):
    ...
```

Comment: `enumerate(x)` is the usual way to do `zip(count(), x)`.

Comment: @zvone, well for only one collection maybe yes, for more maybe is  **your** way. I usually tend to use a single unpack (not nested). Either way there is another answer with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure yours work too but the first answer works better at this point. Thanks